# trying to write a code on rock papers and scissor in python

Tags: python

```
import random as rand
import string
string.letters='rps'
comp = rand.choice(string.letters)
user = input("enter r for rock,p for paper,s for scissors\n")
print(comp)
if comp==user:
    print("its a tie")
elif comp==r and user==p:
    print("  congrats you  won ")
elif comp==r and user==s:
    print("sorry you lost")
elif comp==p and user==r:
    print("sorry you lost") 
elif comp==p and user==s:
    print("  congrats you  won ")
elif comp==s and user==p:
    print("sorry you lost")
elif comp==s and user==r:
    print("  congrats you  won ")
```

and at the output i  am getting the following error:

```
enter r for rock,p for paper,s for scissors
s
r
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "rpcs.py", line 12, in <module>
    elif comp==r and user==p:
NameError: name 'r' is not defined
```

any help would be great thank you

Comment: put `r` in single quotes 'r'. In python the characters should be enclosed with quotes. otherwise it will treat as new variable

Answer (score 2):

Replace things like `r` with `'r'`. Python is reading the `r` you have written as a variable named `r`, and you are treating it as a string. Do the same with `p`, `s`, etc....

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
import random as rand
import string
string.letters='rps'
comp = rand.choice(string.letters)
user = input("enter r for rock,p for paper,s for scissors\n")
print(comp)
if comp==user:
    print("its a tie")
elif comp == 'r' and user == 'p':
    print("  congrats you  won ")
elif comp == 'r' and user == 's':
    print("sorry you lost")
elif comp == 'p' and user == 'r':
    print("sorry you lost") 
elif comp == 'p' and user == 's':
    print("congrats you  won")
elif comp == 's' and user == 'p':
    print("sorry you lost")
elif comp == 's' and user == 'r':
   print("congrats you  won")
```

Explanation:
The characters are need to be used with `quotes`. Otherwise the python take that as variables. As quotes are not used it raised the error `NameError: name 'r' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work because when you perform a conditional test, you are not entering strings. Here is a sample example:

```
import random
strings = ['r', 'p', 's']
computer = strings[random.randint(0, 2)]
user_choice = input("enter r for rock,p for paper,s for scissors:\n")

if computer==user_choice:
    print("its a tie")
elif computer == 'r' and user_choice == 'p':
    print("  congrats you  won ")
elif computer == 'r' and user_choice == 's':
    print("sorry you lost")
elif computer == 'p' and user_choice== 'r':
    print("sorry you lost") 
elif computer == 'p' and user_choice == 's':
    print("  congrats you  won ")
elif computer == 's' and user_choice == 'p':
    print("sorry you lost")
elif computer == 's' and user_choice == 'r':
    print("  congrats you  won ")
else:
    print('Error')
```

Notice that in each conditional test, we enter the values that we are comparing as strings. If they are not string objects they cannot be compared in this example. Simply placing p, r, or s will not work, but they need to be enclosed in quotes as you see. Otherwise, you will get a traceback error.